# Emigrating from USA to United Kingdom

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom

How much money can I take with me when emigrating from USA to United Kingdom without having to pay tax?

Comment: Probably as much as you want? Or, at least, as much as you have.

Answer (score 4):

In both the US and UK you are taxed on your income. Transferring your own money from one country to another does not count as income, so you won't be taxed on it. If it's not your money you are transferring that will be different.

You may have to report transfers to comply with money laundering rules. You have to report large amounts of cash you bring with you.